# Как правильно организовать приложение с использованием MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура

Приветствую. Перечитал по паттерну Model-View-ViewModel немало статей, но до конца пока что не разобрался. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его правильно использовать на конкретном примере ниже.

У меня есть свой WCF-сервис заметок, у которого есть стандартные функции: создать заметку, редактировать, удалить, получить заметки. Сейчас я пишу для него клиент на WPF и хочу применить паттерн MVVM. Расскажите, пожалуйста, что именно должен делать каждый компонент (Model, View, ViewModel). Выводить заметки хочу в `Datagrid`.

Comment: Ради бога, не в DataGrid. Почему программа обязательно должна выглядеть по-энтерпрайзному уродливо?

Comment: @VladD, это первый вариант реализации, самый простой и быстрый. Насколько я понимаю, если архитектура построена правильно, то заменить DataGrid на красивый пользовательский контрол с рисованными листочками бумаги и анимациями будет очень быстро и безболезненно.

Comment: Ого, даже так? Тогда удачи вам и в добрый путь! (Обычно на такой вопрос отвечают в стиле «а в видеокурсах говорили, что для отображения _чего угодно_ нужен DataGrid, в котором Item'ы создаются в OnClick». Приятно удивлён.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модель представляет собой объект домена - короче говоря, то, что вы получаете из WCF. Модель представляет фактические данные и / или информацию, с которой мы имеем дело.

View - это представление данных. В MVVM содержит поведение, события и привязки данных, которые в конечном итоге требуют знания базовой модели и модели просмотра. Короче - это ваш XAML UserControl.

Viewmodel - это концепция сохранения нюансов представления (View) отдельно от модели. С одной стороны он обрабатывает все привязки событий, а с другой - знает, как построить модель и вызвать службу WCF.

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMExample.DetailView">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LineItems}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCommand}" CommandParameter="SubmitPost"/>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class OrderViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public OrderViewModel( IWcfPostService postService )
    {
        this.LineItems = new ObservableCollection<PostItem>(
                           postService.GetPostsList() );
        this.SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(
                                    this.OnSubmit, this.CanSubmit );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PostItem> LineItems { get; private set; }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnSubmit(object arg)   {...}
    private bool CanSubmit(object arg)  { return true; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class PostModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _author;
    private string _text;

    public string Author
    {
        get { return _author; }
        set
        {
            _author = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Author");
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Примерно это я и читал в статьях :) Не могли бы вы привести названия методов, которые необходимы в каждом компоненте паттерна для реализации, например, добавления заметки. Просто чтобы наглядно понимать что происходит, когда пользователь нажимает "Добавить".

Comment: Я обновил ответ, когда пользователь нажимает "Добавить" - нужно будет проверить текст и автора, а затем отправить новое сообщение в WCF

Comment: Спасибо. Буду благодарен, если вы ответите на несколько вопросов по вашему коду: Где происходит собственно обращение к сервису? Кто и как должен обрабатывать `PropertyChanged`? И где вообще мы используем `PostModel`, если в коде выше везде используются `PostItem`'ы?

Comment: @LNK Самый простой пример - http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html - и код - https://github.com/MarkWithall/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example